# Optionally display nav bar in Angular App

Tags: angular, navbar

Beginner to AngularJS.  I want to optionally display my side nav bar. So say I have 5 components Home, SideBar, Page1, Page2 and Page3. Display SideBar if on Home or Page2, but do not display if on Page1 or Page3.
Some pseudo code in my app.component.html I would like something like this:

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>  //Display for Home, Page2
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

What is the best practices way and what is the quick and dirty way to achieving that?
I have seen similar behavior in the context of LogIn page with the use of CanActivate but couldn't really figure out how it would fit my need.

Comment: U can use service and create object conncet this object to navbar buttons and u when u change data in service your navbar will be updated

Comment: app-sidebar itself can subscribe to an event "show or hide" which is set explicitly by any page you want.  Here's one way.  https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech

Answer (score 1):

Define service and write a common method to set the value to a variable

class helperService {

```
 public bSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

    setNavBar(val){
       this.bSubject.next(val);
    }
 public getNavBar(): boolean {
        return this.bSubject.value;
    }
}
```

In everycomponent

```
 if (this.helperService.getNavBar()) {
      this.show=true;
    }else{
this.show=false;
}
```

and set according

```
ngOninit(){

this.helperService.setNavBar(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the best optimized way to achieve this without much changes in the existing components code and will be much easier for the other components too to enable the Sidebar.

Configure your router :

```
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: { sidebar: true }
  },
```

Create a SidebarService to hold/update value specific to route

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class SidebarService {

  private showSidebar$ = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);

  constructor() { }

  setValue(value: boolean) {
    this.showSidebar$.next(value);
  }

  getValue() {
    this.showSidebar$.value;
  }

  getValue$() {
    this.showSidebar$.asObservable;
  }

}
```

Now in your AuthGuard

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: "root"
  })
 export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanDeactivate<any> {

   constructor(private router: Router,
    private sidebarService : SidebarService ) { }

   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     const showSidebar = route["data"]["sidebar] || false;
     this.sidebarService.setValue(showSidebar );
  }
}
```

Now add *ngIf in the selector  and inject the SidebarService 
 service in the component.

In component

```
constructor(private sidebarService : SidebarService ) { }

get showSideBar(){
  return this.sidebarService.getValue$();
}
```

In HTML

```
<app-sidebar *ngIf="showSideBar | async"></app-sidebar> // Use either async pipe or you can have a variable and updating its value by subscribing to this.sidebarService.getValue$()
```

Now you just need to add

```
data: { sidebar: true }
```

in the route you want to enable sidebar. This is the best optimized way I know and may be useful for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I will give it a try.